# Best way to take a live-video-stream and split the image into thirds to broadcast out?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, slice

Can anyone tell me the best tools to make this work?  I basically need to pass a video-feed from an Arduino device, stream it into the cloud, and then have the cloud-video-server "slice" that video feed into thirds (top third, middle third, and bottom-third), and simultaneously stream each of those third-video-slices out to the world via m3u8 (HLS) endpoint.

I know I can pass video up to the cloud via ffmpeg or via RTMP - - - but I haven't found the method yet for the cloud-video-server-based "slicing" process.  I haven't found an ffmpeg way to do it, and I haven't found a Wowza server way to do it, nor an OpenCV way to do it.  Lots of examples of cropping, but I haven't found examples of cropping multiple segments at the same time and streaming out simultaneously.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, but I can address the question on how to split an input into thirds and output each individually. Use the [crop filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop):

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0]crop=iw:ih/3:0:0[top];[0]crop=iw:ih/3[middle];[0]crop=iw:ih/3:0:ih-oh[bottom]" -map "[top]" output-top -map "[middle]" output-middle -map "[bottom]" output-bottom
```